# Why postgresql writes huge temporary files and fills my disk within a loop?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgis, postgresql-9.3, bigdata

**Problem:** The function (below, in PostgreSQL 9.3) runs fine with few iterations, but with many iterations it writes a file of ~1 GB on the disk each iteration until the disk is full and then the code terminates with `failed to write`.

**Question:** Is there a way to not write these files on the disk? Or find some other way to circumvent the problem? Ideally I would like to put the code to run overnight to analyse results next day.

The tables are supposed to be overwritten every iteration, so I don't understand why it fills my disk. In my previous attempts it also ran out of memory but I increased `max_locks_per_transaction = 256` from `64` in the `postgresql.conf`.

**What am I doing:**

I have a function that gets parameters that control the loops inside: start and end timestamp, time bin `delta` time `span` and time `jump`. Something like this: `SELECT ib_run2('2009-06-28 13:30:00', '2009-06-29 13:50:59', '10 minute', '0.5 hour', '24 hour');`

So the function divides time between start and stop into bins, in this example time from `2009-06-28 13:30:00` is divided into `10 minute` intervals for `0.5 hour` then jumps `24 hour` and does that again until `2009-06-29 13:50:59`.

For each 10-minute bin some calculations are made on a spatiotemporal dataset including selection by time and location and calculated distances.

Inside the function there is an unavoidable sequential scan of a big table (6,154,794 rows) and of several smaller ones with selection of a subset from each. The function performs calculations on these subsets and writes results into created tables.

All tables are created with `CREATE TABLE`. Tables starting with `IB_000_` are created before the loops and updated with `INSERT INTO` inside the loops. Tables starting with `IB_i_` are dropped and recreated within the loops each iteration.

Calculation of tables with `IB_i_` involve other tables with `IB_i_`  created within the same iteration or external tables for calculations.

**The function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ib_run2(
        start_dt TEXT DEFAULT '2009-06-28 13:30:00'
      , end_dt   TEXT DEFAULT '2009-06-28 13:59:59'
      , deltat   TEXT DEFAULT '10 minute'
      , spant    TEXT DEFAULT '2 hour'
      , jump_txt TEXT DEFAULT '24 hour'
  ) RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
      DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 1; DECLARE m INT DEFAULT 1; DECLARE iteration INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE delta INTERVAL; DECLARE span INTERVAL; DECLARE jump INTERVAL;
      DECLARE mytext TEXT DEFAULT 'iMarinka';
      DECLARE start_time_query TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now();
      DECLARE dt0 TIMESTAMP;
      DECLARE dt1 TIMESTAMP;
      DECLARE dt TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    dt0:=start_dt :: TIMESTAMP;
    dt1:=end_dt :: TIMESTAMP;
    delta:=deltat :: INTERVAL;
    span:=spant :: INTERVAL;
    jump:=jump_txt :: INTERVAL;
    iteration:=0;

    n:=ceiling(extract(EPOCH FROM (dt1-dt0)          )*1.0/extract(EPOCH FROM (jump ) ));
    m:=ceiling(extract(EPOCH FROM ( (dt0+span) -dt0) )*1.0/extract(EPOCH FROM (delta) ));

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IB_000_times;
    CREATE TABLE IB_000_times (
              gid serial primary key, i INT, j INT
            , t_from_v TIMESTAMP, t_to_v TIMESTAMP
            , t_from_c TIMESTAMP, t_to_c TIMESTAMP
            , t_day TEXT, date_t DATE, t TIME
            , delta_t INTERVAL
            , dt0 TIMESTAMP, dt1 TIMESTAMP
            , dt TIMESTAMP, delta INTERVAL, span INTERVAL , jump INTERVAL );

    mytext:=(m+1)*(n+1)||' iterations '||n+1||' of i '||m+1||' of j'; RAISE NOTICE '%', mytext;

    FOR i IN 0..n LOOP  -----------------------------------------
    FOR j IN 0..m LOOP  -----------------------------------------

      dt := dt0 + j * delta + i * jump;
      iteration := iteration + 1;

      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IB_i_times; 
      CREATE TABLE IB_i_times AS (
        WITH a AS (SELECT dt::DATE date_t, dt::TIME t , delta delta_t)
        SELECT date_t+ t - delta_t AS t_from_v
          , date_t+ t AS t_to_v
          , date_t+ t AS t_from_c
          , date_t+ t + delta_t AS t_to_c
          , to_char(date_t, 'day') AS t_day
          , a.date_t , a.t, a.delta_t
        FROM a
      );

      INSERT INTO IB_000_times (i , j,
          t_from_v , t_to_v , t_from_c , t_to_c , t_day , date_t , t , delta_t ,
          dt0 , dt1 , delta , span , jump , dt)
      SELECT i,j, t.t_from_v, t.t_to_v, t.t_from_c, t.t_to_c, t.t_day, t.date_t, t.t, t.delta_t ,
            dt0 , dt1 , delta , span , jump , dt
      FROM IB_i_times t;

      COPY ( select * FROM IB_000_times ) TO '/Volumes/1TB/temp/IB_000_times.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' ;

      mytext := iteration||'/'||(n+1)*(m+1)||' -----> '||'   dt= '||to_char(dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); RAISE NOTICE '%', mytext;
      mytext := 'Fin '||': i='||i||', dt='|| to_char(dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')||', started  '||start_time_query;

    END LOOP;----------------------------------------------------
    END LOOP;----------------------------------------------------
  RETURN mytext;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Besides the tables `IB_i_times` and `IB_000_times` there is a bunch of other tables (not shown here to save space, the code has ~500 lines) that the function creates before (and some inside) the loops and updates inside the loops.

Comment: It looks like it is possible to replace the procedural code with relational. Just post sample data and desired output.

Comment: if you use temp table, than you can save lot of writes to transaction log. CTE (`with` clause) can generate temp files (does materialization of subqueries, when subqueries are larger than work_mem).

Comment: i do have `WITH` clauses in several tables. but shouldn't it delete them when the iteration is over?

Comment: i'll try `TEMP` tables

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto i have put sample csv files (small ones) and code here: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/650149/Archive.zip

Comment: @Lizardie - PostgreSQL drop these files automatically when the statement finish.

Comment: It does work faster with `TEMP` but still writes files albeit smaller ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say, why Postgres generate temp files from this source code. Use log temp files - `log_temp_files` - and when you identify the statements that produce temp files, you can identify a reason. Usually it is limited `work_mem`.

> Controls logging of temporary file names and sizes. Temporary files can be created for sorts, hashes, and temporary query results. A log entry is made for each temporary file when it is deleted. A value of zero logs all temporary file information, while positive values log only files whose size is greater than or equal to the specified number of kilobytes. The default setting is -1, which disables such logging. Only superusers can change this setting. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html